# How to access the variables inside a class which has been called more than once as a tab in JTabbedPane (Java)

Tags: java, class, applet, netbeans-7

I am creating a java app.

I have one class q2a2 which is a jpanel whose design is shown as follows: -img-

[image]

Suppose if an item is selected from the combo-box and "Create Account" button is clicked. One tab is added to the jTabbedPane. every item has a common tab. so what i did is created one class and adding that everytime on button click. The class name is q2a2_add. This is a panel as well. The image for this is as follows...

[image]

After having some three items the app looks like

[image]

The code for this is:

```
public void addclass(int a) {
    if(jTabbedPane1.getTabCount()<13) { //variable name of TabbedPane
    String s=(String) mainCB.getItemAt(a); //mainCB is the variable name of main combobox
    int dont=0;
        for(int j=0;j<tabname.length;j++){ //just to ensure two accounts should not be same
        if(s.equals(tabname[j])){
            dont=1;
            break;
        }
        }
        if(dont==0){         
        for(int j=0;j<12;j++) {
            if(index[j]==0){
                q2a2_add subpanel2=new q2a2_add(this); //calling the second class
                jTabbedPane1.add(s,subpanel2); //here adding panel
                subpanel2.heading(s); // heading() method is defined in q2a2_add() which rename the jTextField to be same as argument s;
                tabname[j]=s;
                index[j]=1;
                break;
            }
        }
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, (String) mainCB.getItemAt(a)+" is already created","Information", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
}
    else {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Account Overload. Delete wrong account and then create","Caution", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Now my question is. As seen in the function. everytime same class has been called and added. How can i access the various comboboxes and textboxes in different tabs. I want to store and opearate values entered by the user. Like for example- how to read inputs from Accounts Receivable, Accounts Payable and Office Supplies differently.

Please reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expose the functionality that you require within your `q2a2_add` class. For instance, if you want to change the textbox value, add a function inside the `q2a2_add` class called `setTextBoxValue()` that takes a `String` parameter. Inside that function, you can set the textbox value. The same goes for retrieving information from it. The only remaining problem is how to keep track of the different tabs. What I would recommend (which may simplify what you already have) is to create a HashMap which maps `String` types to `q2a2_add` types. Then, when you want to add a new tab panel, you can just check if the `String` exists in the HashMap instead of searching through to check the titles. If it doesn't exist, you can add it to a `HashMap` stored inside of your outer `JPanel` class. Then, when you want to access the tabpanels, you can simply access them by string inside the `HashMap` and get/set their properties as you please.

Comment: I can access the tab panels with the HashMap as you mentioned. But i want to know how to access the variables inside each. I mean.. They basically are children of one class. So isnt they will be same for all the tabs. I mean if i change something. It will be changed for the panels. But this is not happening. I can change each of them differently but how to operate on them.

Comment: can you write the piece code to access read a combo-box value from class q2a2. Say for example combo-box of Account Receivable??

Comment: @Gaurav It would appear that I slightly misunderstood your question. My impression was that each tab (all of the q2a2_add classes) had exactly the same structure. Then you could put the function for setting the textbox in the parent. If not, then you should make a distinct class for each 'type' of tab panel. Then, when somebody makes one, you'll have to cast the type to the tab panel type that you know is correct based on the `String` value for that tab panel.

Comment: By structure, do you mean the no. of combo-boxes and text-boxes. In that case all tabs has the same structure. Exactly same. But my question was, all these boxes basically have the same variable name so how to access say 5th Combo-box of one tab and the same combo of other tab.
Setting a parent is new to me and am curious as well. Can you explain a little

Comment: And regarding adding distinct classes. How can i change the class name each time. Suppose i know the limit of adding tab. Say its 12. So for that do i need to create 12 classes. But that will be copy paste only. But how do i add all those. What code should i write in for loop to change the class name all the time?

Comment: Since the structure is the same across all classes, just expose a function in that class called, for instance, `setTextBoxValue()` like I said above. If you call that function on a single object, then only *that specific tab* will change its textbox value. Then you just need to make sure you're calling it on the "correct" object, which is why I recommended using a HashSet to store the tab panels so you could access them by title.

Comment: For your second question, I would store an array of the titles of the tabs. Then, when you're iterating through your loop, pull the title out of that array and pass it to the constructor.

Comment: @aardvarkk let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1324/discussion-between-gaurav-and-aardvarkk)

Comment: the value will be entered by the user. i dont have to set the values. Can you give the dummy methods to call that function. How can i set the parent. I think if i am able to that. I can access the variables differently